# Dynamicaly add datas in string.Format.

Tags: c#

```
string mystring = "hi {0},how is you, regards {1} ......." //this is dynamic
string[] dataArray = {arun,praveen} ...//this is dynamic
```

and the data which i need to fill data in mystring,data in an array,and also it is dynamic.
let me know how to add content in

```
//string.format(mystring, ..........);
```

always the count in the mysting and the dataArray is same,so there will not be any posiblity of such an error.

Comment: Can you give a sample?

Comment: You can use "dynamic" string and string array in your `String.Format`? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Try [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Format4_Example):

```
string[] dataArray = {"arun","praveen"};
string mystring = String.Format("hi {0},how is you, regards {1}", dataArray);
```

Comment: Am using String.format but how to add the array data in this string.format that ma question

Comment: The array data is the second argument to String.Format:
String.Format("hi {0},how is you, regards {1}", **dataArray**);